# What is "def __iter__(self): return iter(self.file)" for?

Tags: python, django

I'm a somewhat new to python and was looking through the Django source code.  I came across [`utils.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/utils.py), and was somewhat confused about what this iterator method does:

```
def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.file)
```

What would this be used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterating through a file yields all its lines, e.g.:

```
for line in open("foo.txt"):
    print line
```

Results in:

```
line1

line2

line3
```

if `foo.txt` is:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

(extra newlines because `line` includes the newlines of the file).

So, iterating through an instance of the class whose source you posted a snippet from results in iterating through that instance's `file`'s lines.

Comment: In this instance that mixin would probably be used as a base for class that would handle images or other non-text files.  Why would you want to iterate through each line of an image file?

Comment: @HighLife If this is an implementation of the python file interface, I guess it would be more or less mandatory to implement the \__iter__ method, for completeness sake.

Comment: The `__iter__` method is required for the python file interface?  Where can I find more information about the python file interface?

Comment: @HighLife Of course there is no such thing as an interface like in c# or c++. But there is file-like objects: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.next

Comment: Oh wait, c++ doesn't have interfaces either ;)

Comment: @HighLife: ah i just assumed it would be a text file. is `self.file` an actual file object (gotten with `open`)? or is it something else?

Comment: Claudiu: see the link @HighLife provided. The name of the class says it all.

Answer (score 2):

`__iter__` is invoked on some object when it is passed as an argument to `iter()`.  In other words, if you call `iter(a)`, behind the scenes, python will ultimately call `a.__iter__()` by default.

For this particular implementation, it will then return the iterator for the `file` member, whatever that may be.